# Formats supported by iPhone media player

Tags: iphone

Whether iPhone media player support .wmv and .wma? What are the other formats that iPhone media player supports?

Answer (score 2):

Listed here, assuming you are using the standard controller:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot for your quick reply.But after googling I have found in an article that it supports these formate.I am giving the link below

http://www.phones-online.org/phones/iphone/iphone-software/new-iphone-media-player-software-mplayer.html

Please look at the link and please cleare these thinks,I am very much confuse.

Comment: Is this a programming question or are you just trying to play video on the iPhone?

Comment: It is aprogramming question.I want to create an app that play those formates directly.